# Cannot find HTML element to send Tab key to

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium Chromedriver (Java) to navigate around a webpage. I need to send a Tab key many times (50+) to explore the entire webpage. However I cannot determine which element to send the Tab key to, so I keep getting WebDriverException: element not interactable errors.

Is there some way to determine which element is handling the Tab? I have tried many different HTML elements on the page but could find the correct one.

Thanks!

Comment: try with WebElement element = driver.switchTo().activeElement();

Comment: Just an idea, maybe you could use the Robot class like it is shown here https://automationtalks.com/2017/06/17/tab-key-button-selenium/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one more option is using action class.Just keep this statements in loop as per your need.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
action.sendKeys(Keys.TAB).bui‌​ld().perform();
```